# How come this loop doesn't print out six numbers?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
package p22_09_24;

public class Lotto2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i <6; i++) {
            i = (int)(Math.random()*45)+1;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the exit is under the 'for' which means it should loop six times, but the answer is only one num.

Comment: `i` is changed inside of loop, so total number of iterations is not always 6, because of random it can be anything

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to use two different variables here - one for the loop index, and another to store the random number.  Maybe you could write `int r = (int)(Math.random()*45)+1;` instead of reusing `i`.

Comment: An important aspect of programming is **looking** at your code and **thinking** about what it is actually doing. If your condition is `i < 6` and inside your loop you're reassigning `i` to something that is probably bigger than 6, then the loop will stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random()*45)+1;
            System.out.println("Random number is: " + randomNumber);
        }
    }

}
```

use different name to store the random number.